# Remove <br> and white-space from paragraph

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, primeng

I add comments via PrimeNG text editor and then display the comments in a div. However, If user press enter button 5 times, it adds the html content five paragraph as expected and there are 4 empty lines displayed in the div. So, in order to remove empty line breaks, I tried to use similar approach as following:

```
div p, div br {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
br {
    display: none;
}

p br {
    display: none;
}
```

But I have not managed to remove unnecessary line breaks and white spaces (I also want to remove them if user gives too long space by using space key when adding comments). So, how can I do this?

Comment: it sounds like you are looking for a character counter on your text, you could use that to limit the length

Comment: You can use :empty css selector if you're div is completely empty

Comment: @EnterStrandman I already applied maximum character control, but what is the user enters "(45 space) +                                             abcde" for an 50 character (max) field?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a regex to change modify the text when saving? If that's so you may try this to remove break lines

```
output.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n\n')
```

The second parameter may be used to set how many breaklines you'd like to let (1, 2, or even zero).

Something similar can be done to remove when "user gives too long space by using space key".

```
output.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
```

I hope this may help you out.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it was helpful but not solved the problem completely. Voted up.

Comment: What's left to completly sove it? I might come out with something :)